# Replicating data for ease of access

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

I have a table, lets call table a, that I allow users to enter data into. They can enter data as many times as they want, and based on some constraints, I only use the most recent entry.

My question is this: is it okay to take the entered data from table a, simplify it (take the most recent data, apply some formulas), and store it in table b?

This improves access access for my application and convert makes most of my data access queries simple selection statements. The down side is that my data is replicated, and a script must be run regularly to keep data in sync.

So, is this an acceptable practice?

Comment: Everything is acceptable... as far as it works for your use-case (and doesn't put the world at risk of any deadly catastrophe)  ;-) - Is this uncommon? Not really, you're actually emplying a *poor man's version* of a materialized view.

Comment: @joanolo I had no idea that was what it was called. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the classic case of `History` versus `CurrentState`.  Sure, have two tables.  Insert a new row into `History` and overwrite the row keyed to the user in the other table.

That does lead to "redundant" data, which is a 'no-no' by DB purists.  So here is another approach:

Insert into History, as above.  Get back the `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.  Then Update the `CurrentState` with just the id (and user_id).  Then, for accessing the current info, use a `JOIN` between the tables.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, thank you! What do you think of storing results of a function in a new table, vs calling them on demand?

Comment: "results of a function" -- is this related, or a separate function?  How complex is the function?